# How do I run `iex -S mix` without compiling changed files?

Tags: compiler-errors, elixir, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

Say I'm writing a new module, the code isn't ready yet and I want to test something in the repl.
I run `iex -S mix` and it fails because of compilation errors I didn't intend to fix yet.

I presume there is a last compiled version of my app that I could run with `iex`.
How do I do that?

Comment: I could start an `iex` session before changing the files but I often forget to do so. Also I could reset the project state with git but maybe there's an easier way.

Answer (score 18):

`mix` is a shortcut to `mix run`. If you invoke `mix help run`, you will see there are many options there, including a `--no-compile` one. Therefore:

```
iex -S mix run --no-compile
```